# replace Nth word in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace the Nth word of a string with another word in javascript. For example:

```
<div id="sentence">This is some sentence that has the word is.</div>
```

Replace the second word of this sentence, `is`, with `was` leaving the `is` at the end untouched. I thought the following would work but it does not:

```
var p = new RegExp('(?:\\S+ ){1}(\\S+)');
$("#sentence").html(function(k,v) {return v.replace(p, "was");});
```

Comment: Does it say anywhere in that homework assignment(?) that you can not simply replace the first occurrence of `is` (looking for a word boundary before it, so that it doesn’t replace “this”), without caring about that it happens to be the second word? `"This is some sentence that has the word is.".replace(/\bis/, "was")`

Comment: yes this is just a simple example, in reality the thing i need to do is more complicated so it has to be second word rather than identifying the actual word.

Comment: is it going to be the second always?

Comment: no not second always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capture group and add it to the replace value with `$1`

```
var p = new RegExp('^((\\S+ ){1})(\\S+)');
$("#sentence").html(function(k,v) {return v.replace(p, "$1was");});
```

Full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
  </head>
 <body>
  <div id="sentence">This is some sentence that has the word is.</div>
  <script>
   var p = new RegExp('^((\\S+ ){1})(\\S+)');
   $("#sentence").html(function(k,v) {return v.replace(p, "$1was");});
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Explanation:

`^` Matches the beginning of the string.

`(\\S+ ){n}` Repeats n times, but this would also repeat the capture. (Keeping only the last group captured.)

`((\\S+ ){1})`  Embed the repeat inside a capture group. `$1`

`(\\S+ ){1}` This is now the second capture group. `$2`  Only the last iteration is stored in `$2`

`(\\S+)` Capture the extra word to be replaced. `$3`

`v.replace(p, "$1was");` $1 adds the first capture group and back into the string.  The second capture group is left out.

Comment: awesome! can you explain the `((\\S+ ){1})` portion: specifically, how does regex treat embedded captures of this type?

Comment: `(){3}`  Repeat capturing into `$1` (Only last capture is retained)

`((){3})` Repeat capturing into `$2`. Capture entire group in `$1`.

Start counting groups by the `(`.  The group still ends at the matching `)`.